# convert a list to dict with key equal to every unique item and value equal to the indices of the item in the list

Tags: python

For example, I have a list of `a = ['a', 'b', 'a']`, what is the best code to convert it to `b = {'a': [0, 2], 'b': [1]}`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `list` default factory:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'a']
>>> res = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, s in enumerate(a):
...     res[s].append(i)
... 
>>> res
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [0, 2], 'b': [1]})
```

Parameter given to `defaultdict` is a function that will be called to provide initial value in case that given key doesn't exist. Since original list is being iterated once and time complexity of `list.append` is **O(1)** the total time complexity is **O(n)**.

**Update** Performance comparison of different solutions:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def test1(l):
    b = dict.fromkeys(set(l), [])
    for i, val in enumerate(l):
       b[val] = b.get(val)+[i]

def test2(l):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for i, s in enumerate(l):
        res[s].append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test1(['a'] * 1000)", setup="from __main__ import test1", number=10))
    print(timeit.timeit("test2(['a'] * 1000)", setup="from __main__ import test2", number=10))
```

Output:

```
0.03234261799661908
0.000929353991523385
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a']
b = dict.fromkeys(set(a), []) # {'a': [], 'b': []}
for i, val in enumerate(a):
  b[val].append(i)

print (b)
```

gives:

```
{'a': [0, 2], 'b': [1]}
```

Comment: Since this generates a new list on every iteration the worst case time complexity is **O(n^2)** so it's not feasible with longer lists at least if most the the indices contain same value.